# Want to implement APIs in Rails

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to write APIs for my rails 3.1 application but have never written an API ever. I am supposed to write REST and SOAP APIs. Is there a formal book or e-book or screencasts or tutorials which teaches about APIs in Rails and best practices?

Comment: Not Rails-specific, but a good starting point for REST: http://www.amazon.com/Restful-Web-Services-Leonard-Richardson/dp/0596529260/

Comment: Clearly this book covers a whole lot of words I hear in relation to APIs. Good starting point to learn basics. Thanks!! Is there a book that handles API writing best practices in rails specifically?

Answer (score 2):

have a look at [Grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape/wiki). It's a micro-framework to build REST apis, with a [rails implementation example](http://martinciu.com/2011/01/mounting-grape-api-inside-rails-application.html) provided.
As for SOAP, don't know, but [Savon](http://savonrb.com/) seems fine.

Comment: I will surely check them out. Though right now I am looking to learn basics and whats OOB in Rails. I'm still a Newbie. :)